# Get rid of spaces between lines in html

Tags: html, styles, space

The following html code creates two hyperlinks in consecutive lines with

1. Space in between
2. Underlined links.

How do I get rid of both 1 and 2 ?

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><font face="monospace" font size="4" style="text-decoration:none;"><pre>[    Text1]</pre></font></a>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><font face="monospace" font size="4" style="text-decoration:none;"><pre>[    Text2]</pre></font></a>
```

Comment: #1 - put your HTML on 1 line.  I know it sounds crazy.

Comment: Is this a serious question? Why would you use the relative URL www.stackoverflow.com, and why would you use `pre` for link annotations (or whatever you have there)? And use pointlessly invalid markup?

Comment: Jukka - It is part of a Perl generated log html(Not a webpage). I wanted it to be properly formatted for easy reading in a browser

Answer (score 1):

1#
`<pre>` tag causes that "space". `<pre>` has some margins above and bottom. ***margin: 0;*** makes the magic.

```
<style>
    pre { margin: 0; }
</style>
```

2#
Add your style tag ***style="text-decoration:none;"*** inside  tag, not inside `<font>` tag.

Also I recommend you to forget inline styling and make your styling in external .css file or between `<style></style>` tags. Using inline style tags is a bit oldish and makes your code look complex. Believe me, it will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="word-spacing: 3px;">
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="www.stackoverflow.com"><font face="monospace" font size="4"><pre style="margin: 0;float:left;">[    Text1]</pre></font></a>
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="www.stackoverflow.com"><font face="monospace" font size="4"><pre style="margin: 0;">[    Text1]</pre></font></a>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vxAkG/1)

This may help you!

**The less `word-spacing` the more gap in between.**

Comment: Please note that I want space before Text1 and Text2

Comment: Should be said that inline CSS is considered bad practice. Of course it's perfectly fine for demonstration only.